# if $f: D\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \to R$ is continuous at $a \in D$, then there exists a $\delta > 0$ s.t $f$ is continuous on $B(a, \delta)$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, epsilon-delta

### Question:

Is it true that if $f: D\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \to R$ is continuous at $a \in D$, then there exists a $\delta > 0$ s.t $f$ is continuous on $B(a, \delta)$ ?

### Reasoning:

if $f$ is continuous at $a \in D$, given $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists \delta >0$ s.t 
$$f(B(a, \delta) ) \subseteq B(f(a), \epsilon),$$
so take $\delta_1 > 0$ in such a way that $c\in B(a, \delta)$ and $B(c, \delta_1) \subseteq B(a, \delta)$ (it is trivial to show the existence of $\delta_1$).

Now, we do know that $f (B(c, \delta_1)) \subseteq B(f(a), \epsilon)$, but how about $f (B(c, \delta_1)) \subseteq B(f(c), \epsilon_1)$ where $\epsilon > \epsilon_1 > 0$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot prove it because it's false.

Take for example the [modified Dirichlet function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function):
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0 & \text{if } x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q},\\
\frac{1}{q} & \text{if } x=\frac{p}{q}\text{ as reduced fraction.}\end{cases}
$$

This function is continuous in the irrationals and discontinuous in the rationals, so you cannot find such an open set around $\sqrt{2}$ where $f$ is continuous, as the rationals are dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Though $f$ seems as a good counterexample, I am a bit confused. Isn't this function continuous in the irrationals with respect to neighbourhoods of irrationals? In other words, does it satisfy classical definition of continuity, i.e. given $\epsilon$ there will always be a neighbourhood $U \subset \mathbb{R}$ mapped by $f$ inside the $\epsilon$ neighbourhood of the given mapped irrational point? Because it seems to me that precisely the fact that the rationals are dense in $\mathbb{R}$ will cause the classical definiton to crash.

Comment: @RadekSuchánek It satisfies the classical $\varepsilon,\delta$-definition. The key in proving this is that you can eradicate all fractions with denominator too far from $0$ from the neighbourhood by choosing $\delta$ small enough. So there are still rationals in the neighbourhood, but they are close enough to $0$, so continuous.

Comment: I see, thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another example, why it is false. Consider the following function

$$ g(x) = \begin{cases} 0,& x\in \mathbb{Q}, \\
x^2,& x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}. \end{cases} $$

It is continuous in 0 (even differentiable), as we have

$$ 0\leq \left\vert \frac{g(x) - g(0)}{x-0} \right\vert 
\leq \left\vert \frac{x^2}{x} \right\vert
= \vert x \vert \rightarrow 0, \qquad x\rightarrow 0.$$

Thus, by the squeeze theorem, we get $g'(0)=0$. However, for $x\neq 0$ the function is not continuous.

Take $x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$, and a sequences $(y_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq\mathbb{Q}$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} y_n = x$. Then we have

$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f(y_n) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} 0 = 0 \neq x^2 = f(x). $$

Thus, $f$ is not continuous in $x$. Similarly one can argue for $x\in \mathbb{Q}\setminus \{0\}$.